# remote access to mysql database through user interface

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, laravel

I have my *Laravel app hosted on amazon EC2(instance)*. Now, as users are increasing on the app, my database is growing.

*Earlier, I used to take a dump of the my database* from that instance *and fed it on local* and visualized it using navicat. But now, as the database is growing, this process is becoming more time taking.

So, I just want to know - **is there some method/tool using which I can access a remote database(like the one on that EC2 instance) graphically(using an interface like Navicat or something else) and not just through command line?**

*I know how to do it using command line* but I want a way to access a remote database through user interface. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using SQLYog Community Edition which I use on all my Amazon ECS hosted MySQL databases. It is absolutely fantastic and with the copy database to another host/database feature saves me tons of time and effort.

Link to download
https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

You can access remote host with `phpMyAdmin`, but you need to configure it properly... Full instruction [under this link](http://www.danielmois.com/article/Manage_remote_databases_from_localhost_with_phpMyAdmin). `Navicat` can access remote databases as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you could.

If you are using MySQL, then you could remotely connect to the MySQL on the EC2 Instance using [MySQL WorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). The advantage being, you could run your queries and other stuff in the GUI part of the WorkBench itself. It would be more helpful if you mention what kind of visualizations are you looking at (does it require more than querying)